# Symfony ApiPlatform custom DELETE action triggers default remove event

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have a question on api platform custom routes functionality. When trying to implement custom route with DELETE method the event system is triggered for object in http request (that is found by param converter):

```
* @ApiResource(
*     attributes={
*         "normalization_context": {
*         },
*         "denormalization_context": {
*         },
*     },
*     itemOperations={
*     },
*     collectionOperations={
*         "customObjectRemove": {
*             "method": "DELETE",
*             "path": "/objects/{id}/custom_remove",
*             "controller": CustomObjectRemoveController::class,
```

So, even I have written my own logic in controller my entity is always triggered for removal in api platform event system. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Can you please provide more code for how you implemented your routers?

Comment: @Johan Updated.  I've used ApiResource annotations in my model. My controller is api platform style - it has __invoke method. In controller if I return my object entity - api platform will trigger remove event, if it returns nothing - it's okay

Answer (score 3):

you can implement an event subscriber that implements EventSubscriberInterface:

```
<?php 
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;


final class DeleteEntityNameSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
   

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Inject the services you need
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['onDeleteAction', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE]
        ];
    }

    public function onDeleteAction(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $object = $event->getControllerResult();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $method = $request->getMethod();

        if (!$object instanceof MyEntity || Request::METHOD_DELETE !== $method) {
            return;
        }

       // Do your staff here
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think it works. After the subscriber, the default method will still be called.

Comment: Take a look here https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers

An other way using Doctrine subscribers

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but it appears in google results.

You can configure your route to not delete your entity by adding `write: false` which disables the automatic delete and flush functions of the endpoint:

```
collectionOperations={
 *         "customObjectRemove": {
 *             "method": "DELETE",
 *             "path": "/objects/{id}/custom_remove",
 *             "controller": CustomObjectRemoveController::class,
 *             "write": false
```

note: you will need to add the `flush` in your event subscriber or controller, otherwise the changes won't be saved.